Lazy Treap implementation fails to be lazy
I'm currently trying to solve the CSES problem "Substring Reversals". I'm solving this by using a lazy treap. I've compared my solution to this one, posted on a codeforces forum, and I don't see any major difference. However, my treap doesn't appear to be very lazy, and more just bad. My code is as follows:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int priority=rand(),sz=1;
    char value;
    bool flip=0;
    Node *l=nullptr, *r=nullptr;
    Node(char _value): value(_value){}
};
using NodePtr = Node*;
 
int get_sz(NodePtr t)
{
    return t ? t->sz : 0;
}
 
void pull_sz(NodePtr t)
{
    if(t) t->sz = get_sz(t->l) + get_sz(t->r) + 1;
}
void push_lz(NodePtr t){
    if (t && t->flip){
        t->flip = 0;
        swap(t->l,t->r);
        if (t->l) t->l->flip ^= 1;
        if (t->r) t->r->flip ^= 1;
    }
}
void split(NodePtr t, NodePtr &l, NodePtr &r, int k){
    if (!t) {
        l = r = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    int rank = get_sz(t->l) + 1;
    push_lz(t);
    if(rank <= k)
    {
        l = t;
        split(l->r, l->r, r, k-rank);
    }
    else
    {
        r = t;
        split(r->l, l, r->l, k);
    }
    pull_sz(l);
    pull_sz(r);
}
void merge(NodePtr &t, NodePtr l, NodePtr r){
    push_lz(l);
    push_lz(r);
    if(!l) t = r;
    else if(!r) t = l;
    else if (l->priority > r->priority){
        t = l;
        merge(t->r, t->r, r);
    }
    else {
        t = r;
        merge(t->l, l, t->l);
    }
    pull_sz(t);
}
 
NodePtr find_by_order(NodePtr t, int k)
{
    if(!t) return t;
    int lsz = get_sz(t->l);
    if(k == lsz)
    {
        return t;
    }
    else if(k < lsz)
    {
        return find_by_order(t->l, k);
    }
    else
    {
        return find_by_order(t->r, k-lsz-1);
    }
}
 
NodePtr build(const string& v, int lb, int rb)
{
    if(lb == rb)
    {
        return new Node(v[lb]);
    }
 
    int mb = (lb+rb)/2;
    NodePtr l = build(v, lb, mb);
    NodePtr r = build(v, mb+1, rb);
    NodePtr t;
    merge(t, l, r);
    return t;
}
 
void output(NodePtr t)
{
    if(!t) return;
    push_lz(t);
    output(t->l);
    cout << t->value;
    output(t->r);
}
 
int main(){
    int n,t;
    string s;
    cin >> n >> t;
    cin >> s;
    NodePtr tr = build(s,0,n-1);
    while (t--){
        int a,b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        a--;b--;
        NodePtr l,m,r;
        split(tr,l,m,a);
        split(m,m,r,b-a+1);
        if (m) m->flip ^= true;
        merge(tr,l,m);
        merge(tr,tr,r);
    }
    output(tr);
}

When running this code on the input:
5 2
ABCDE
1 5
1 4

It prints out
ABCDE

Which is obviously wrong, and indicates that the lazy property isn't being properly pushed on splits. However, my split function appears functionally identical to the one I linked earlier, except for the way we keep track of the index. What's the problem in my implementation? Thanks!
UPDATE: Found the bug, turns out in the split function I mixed up the order of the pull_sz and push_lz calls, and the pull_sz should be after the push_lz, since the push_lz might change the subtree relevant to the pull_sz(t->l)

and I don't see any major difference -- That is not how to compare programs.  You need to actually run both programs (preferably under a debugger) to determine where and when the differences occur.  You cannot tell by sight whether two programs will behave the same, unless one program is a direct copy and paste of the other.

Of course there is a difference, as the linked code works and my doesn't. I've compared both split functions in both implementation and functionality and couldn't pickup on anything too drastic except for small quirks in how the linked solution handles the subtree size counting

So did you run your program or the linked one under a debugger with the test data?

I did, and since everything is pointers to structures and such, I didn't find debugging to be helpful, especially considering that we did implement other things differently. I am, however, sure that my underlying implicit treap is correct, as it passed the tests on the cses problem "Cut and Paste".

"I didn't find debugging to be helpful" that means you need to debug better, not to give up. "my underlying implicit treap is correct", you said in your post yours was not behaving correctly. This is one of the problems (among many) of these so called competitive programming sites. Passing whatever sad tests they have is no proof of correctness.

No no, I said that my lazy implicit treap is misbehaving. My underlying implicit treap structure (Which means all the parts that don't involve the lazy operation) is correct.

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Not really relevant to competitive programming questions, but still appreciated nonetheless

Not really relevant to competitive programming questions -- Tell that to the many competitive programming questioners who have come here to ask "why does my swap function not get called or doesn't work?" or "why am I getting these compiler errors on the variable I declared as int data;?".  I didn't find debugging to be helpful" -- Honestly, saying that as a software developer would get you fired.  Debugging is basically the only way, other than maybe looking at output logs, to figure out a problem with a program.  Rarely are non-trivial programs corrected "by sight alone".
